# How to keep a form element fixed to bottom of screen in display whilst scrolling?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a quick question. On my website https://www.metis-online.com, if you scroll all the way down the page, you will see an email marketing search box.

What I would like is for that to always be displayed on screen fixed to the bottom so that no matter if the user is scrolling up or down. that marketing searchbar is always in view at the bottom.

Pretty much it's like my top nav bar but for the bottom of the screen. Issue is whilst it is simple to do a fixed-top for a nav bar as it's part of the <`nav>` element, the marketing search box is a bit more tricky as it's a not a `.

Below is the code for this, how can I set it?

```css
/*--------Marketing Email-------*/

#marketing-email {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.8));*/
  background-color: #5398ff;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #1034A6;
}

#market-email {
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 30%;
}

.marketing-btn {
  background: #1034A6;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="marketing-email">
  <form class="marketing-email-form" method="post" action="#mailing_list_email_sent">
    <div>
      <label for="email"><b>Stay updated on our new courses and services by joining our mailing list</b></label><br/>
      <input type="email" id="market-email" name="market-email" required placeholder="Email" />
      <button type="submit" class="marketing-btn">Send</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `position: fixed;`?

```
#marketing-email {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Strange, when I tried your answer, it causes the marketing email form to disappear

Comment: Did you set the `bottom` property? I tried that in your site and it works